# symbolic substitution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

The function subs in matlab does not work as expected with me. I define a symbolic variable, then assign it a value of 0, but later I discover it has not been assigned anything.

```
syms x1
a=x1
subs(a,x1,0)
a
```

produces

```
x1
```

and not 0. Any ideas?

Comment: just to add a note that matlab doesn't work in "Pointer-style referencing". So your a is still unmodified.You need to get the return value as @Dan has mentioned in his answer to get the result you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my documentation for MATLAB:

> subs(s,old,new) returns a copy of s replacing all occurrences of old with new, and then evaluating s.

`subs` doesn't modify `a`, it returns a modified version of it. For example, try this:

```
syms x1;
a = x1;
b = subs(a,x1,0);
a
b
```

Returns

```
a = x1
b = 0
```

Comment: What would be the best strategy if I want to assign an initial value for, say, x1? And later on I still need it as a symbolic variable...

Comment: @student1 That's sort of the reason `subs` works the way it does. You can have `a_sym = x1` and keep `a_sym` around as a symbolic variable for as long as you need it, and then any time you want to assign a variable, you do `a = subs(a_sym, x1, 0)`. You still have the symbolic expression in case you need it later.